# Mesothermic clothes?

Tags: biology, clothing, reptiles

I've been agonizing over this for a while now.
In my world, there are a group of lizardmen called the Varal. They live in desert climates are mostly inspired by predatory lizards like Moniters & Tegu and that bunch.

They're mesothermic like dinosaurs, despite looking like upright lizards with opposable thumbs. They're pretty intelligent, think Neanderthals or Denisovans, so they have fairly advanced culture/language/handicrafts.

Not many organisms live where they do, Jerboa, Cats, and they herd giant herbivorous lizards. Cactuses sometimes grow there, and they sometimes grow those for water.

My question is though, how would the clothing/armor of these creatures look? I don't want to just do a boring cape or human like clothing, I want to make something that looks like they invented it independently.

Comment: You would need to consider what materials are available to them in their environment, and we would need that information to have any realistic way of answering this question.

Comment: @MontyWild Okay

Comment: I think that you also need to specify what kind of function do you want clothing/armour to perform. For example, do the Varal need protection from the elements (if yes, what are they vulnerable to)? Or are there any specific cultural elements that influence clothing (e.g. we humans have an idea of modesty that affects clothing a lot)? I would also recommend looking into the history of fashion, especially traditional clothing. It could provide you with some reference material and give some idea about how desired functions translate into specific forms.

Answer (score 1):

**Mica / metal reflective body paint.**

[image: reflective body paint]

https://www.deviantart.com/demonabast/art/Metallic-Body-Paint-215151229

In ages past these lizard people were hunted by predators.  These people have since wiped out the predators, but the lizard people retain the cryptic
skin coloring that protected their ancestors.

Light colors are better for reflecting the sun and shiny metallic colors the best of all.  Also, the lizard people can perceive the light and shiny colors better.  Persons going without body paint are sometimes called the name of the domestic herbivorous lizards, which have a similar basal coloring as these lizard people.  The implications are obvious.

The paint is made from desert minerals - mostly mica but some metallic pigments.  There are color and accent variations but the basic lizard person is painted with silver-gray reflective mica.

Answer (score 1):

## Black and white

Given that these organisms are mesothermic, they spend energy to heat their bodies, but don't need to maintain a specific target temperature.  This is usually described as an intermediate between warm- and cold-blooded, though in truth it seems the most advanced possibility, with all the advantages of warm-blooded metabolism and yet with the flexibility to survive using a wide range of temperatures as needed, rather than a more limited range of fever or hibernation states.

With trade-offs for different metabolic regimes, it seems inevitable that these creatures will want to be the masters of the quick change.  Sometimes they will want to hibernate, figuratively or literally, consuming little energy and aging quite slowly.  Other times they will want to maintain the maximum temperature their proteins have evolved to handle without denaturing, for bursts of frenetic activity.  Yet neither of these states in itself tells us what they need for clothing, because hard exertion might warm them too much, and hibernation might leave them with little time to react to a cold snap.  They will want to have black clothing to warm up by the bright sunlight of day, or cool down in the cold desert night; and warm clothing (perhaps even reflective) to insulate them better against sudden changes.  They will want thick layers of clothing to preserve their expensive metabolic heat production, or to help them stay cool when settling down on the cold ground before a hot day.  Options... lots of options ... will be paramount.

In view of this, I picture them dressing in layers, with a thick white parka-like material that they can wrap around themselves or drape over themselves and the ground beneath them, and a thin black chador-like material they keep underneath meant to maximize the rate of temperature equilibration.  The "white parka" would be worn from the center of the back (they may have small spines they can hook it on) and draped or folded, or when not in use, rolled neatly together like a long skinny backpack.  The black clothing would be designed to be more form-fitting, without as much need for quickly changing it, balancing between thinness for heat exchange and some thickness as a barrier to abrasion.  ("Lizards" are not known for particularly robust immunity against skin infections ...)